# How do I disable a full-Text Search on a column in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, alter

I'm trying to convert a column from ntext to nvarchar(MAX), but it seems there is a Full-Text search enabled on it.

```
Alter table <table> alter column <column> nvarchar
```

Then i'm going to force the text into rows

```
update <table> set <column> = <column> +'' where <column> is not null
```

Finally I'll need to enable the full text search again.

How do I do this in SQL?

Comment: This question is obsolete in newer SQL Server versions. Instead, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034607/error-cannot-alter-or-drop-column-x-because-it-is-enabled-for-full-text-searc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DROP FULLTEXT INDEX ON mytable.mycolumn;
go
Alter table ... nvarchar(value);
go
ADD FULLTEXT INDEX ON mytable add (mycolumn)
```

(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188359.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

This is to SQL Server 2005.

#### Syntax to drop Fulltext Index:

ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON **[TABLENAME]** DROP **(COLUMNNAME)**

-- ALTER COLUMN OR MORE STATEMENT --

#### Syntax to Readd FullText Index:

ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON **[TABLENAME]** add **(COLUMNNAME)**

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON TableName drop (ColumnName)
ALTER TABLE TableName ALTER COLUMN ColumnName nvarchar(MAX)
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON TableName add (ColumnName)
```

This will drop the column from the index, then you alter it, and after this, you re-add it to the index.